# How to find the natural solutions of the equation?

Tags: combinations

I have this problem:

> "Find all possible combinations, to form `$12000` With `$10000`  `$5000` and `$1000`"

***I read a posibble solutions is:***

Find all natural solutions to:  `10a + 5b + c = 12`

**Further, already solved this, only testing the combinatios.**

But how i can do with more combinations? Imagine the combinations were 50 or more, it would be a waste of time.

*so, the best method is find the natural solutions? and how to do that?*

Comment: There's a good question somewhere here, but it's awfully hard to understand.  I suppose you're really asking, what is a general solution for this *type* of problem, so you could easily solve (for example) "How many ways are there to form $350 using pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, dollar bills, fives, tens, twenties, fifties and hundreds?"

Comment: Yes, those currencies are from my country, but any currency would apply.

Comment: Problems of this type are solved with [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).